# Flex 4.6 Mobile App List item height issue

Tags: ios, apache-flex, mobile, dpi, flex4.6

Is there any way to dynamically change the padding between each row in an itemRenderer List for Mobile Air Apps (iOS)?

At the moment I'm using conditional CSS to detect what resolution the device is and change the font size in the list accordingly. However I can't seem to change the padding on-top nor below each item.

You can see what I mean by clicking here:

[image: app-emulator]

Thanks for all your help and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting (for example through CSS or extend it and make your custom item renderer for the List) the `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` of the [LabelItemRenderer](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/mobilecomponents/src/spark/components/LabelItemRenderer.as)

Comment: Good idea Alexander, will give that a try